# My texture does not appear

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

[image]

I think that i deleted the original geo that i did use to creates instances

now when i set a material to these instances nothing happens

how to fix that ?

Comment: we don't see your modifiers, we don't even see the whole node tree of your material - so pls provide blend file, so we can check it out. thx

Comment: If you're using Geo Nodes, make sure the tree is 'Set Material' is there, and pointing  the right way..